# How do I load iwlwifi driver?

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

I'm trying to use my onboard wifi, and it doesn't seem to be loading.  Using kernel `5.2.13` which is the latest in Ukku. (Gigabyte X570 Aorus Master)

```
16:00 $ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
✔ ~ 
16:01 $ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0084]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
✔ ~ 
16:01 $ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
✔ ~ 
16:02 $ dmesg | grep iwl
[    5.530176] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.549237] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.549245] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.549253] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.549260] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.549266] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.549273] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.549280] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.549286] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-41.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.549290] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-40.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.549295] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-39.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.549296] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[    5.549297] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-cc-a0-39
[    5.549298] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-cc-a0-48
[    5.549298] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

I found some articles indicating that this device should be supported as of the 5.1 kernel, but it's not loading.

Comment: As of 19.10 Pop!_OS (and I presume Ubuntu), it's supported out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, I also needed to download and extract the [AX200 wifi drivers from Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html?productId=189347&localeCode=us_en) and move them into `/lib/firmware`

Comment: I tried this, but did not solve it for me :(

Comment: @Rohan are you using a recent (like newer than when I posted my reply) Linux Kernel?  If you're running a 20.10 ubuntu derivative or similar, it should be in the box at this point.

Comment: After trying a LOT of things, I figured Windows Fast Boot was casuing the problem somehow. I still don't understand how a different OS can do that, but I guess it has something to do with hibernation files that it stores before it shuts down, and it was messing up the wifi driver in elementary OS somehow. So I turned it off, and now it is fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Intel has distributed a bunch of AX200 firmware and they made their way into the kernel firmware repository
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204731#c35
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/
you could try those recent firmware that needs to be installed in /lib/firmware.
However, as the compiled kernel has bindings to the specific firmware file.
You would do better if you upgrade the kernel.
i did this successfully afterinstalling ubuntu 20.10 distribution and doing apt-get update and apt-get upgrade, when all it done it turns out the latest AX200 firmware is distributed
if you read the bug report in the first link, the earlier firmwares has got various bummers, so do use as recent firmware as is possible

Comment: When I posted, I was using a bleeding edge kernel, and still needed to add the drivers myself... can see my own answer above.